# Get Video Duration of a YouTube Video with youtube v3 API c#

Tags: c#, youtube-data-api

I tried to get the the length of a Video i searched before, with the youtube v3 API you can download at nuget.org.

I know there are a lot of solution, but they are always written in php.

That is the code I am using Right now:

```
var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
earchListRequest.Q = Find;
searchListRequest.MaxResults = 5;



var searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();
foreach (var searchResult in searchListResponse.Items)
        {
            switch (searchResult.Id.Kind)
            {
                case "youtube#video":
                break;
            }
        }
```

Thanks for any kind of help :)

Comment: And what issue you are facing with this code? Can you share the php code which inspired you to write this code?

Comment: I need some way to access the Duration of the SearchResult. I used this code: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can donwlaod the Json version of the video :

```
    WebClient myDownloader = new WebClient();
    myDownloader.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

   string jsonResponse=myDownloader.DownloadString(
   "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=" + yourvideoID+ "&key=" 
   + youtubekey + "&part=contentDetails");
   dynamic dynamicObject = Json.Decode(jsonResponse);
   string tmp = dynamicObject.items[0].contentDetails.duration;
   var Duration = Convert.ToInt32
   (System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan(tmp).TotalSeconds);
```

Comment: It marks me **Json.Decode**. I assume i have to install some kind of nuget?

Comment: you have to install this on nuget :
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.YouTube.v3/1.32.0.1079,
then use "resolve..." in visual studio as usual

Comment: replace "var" dynamicObject with "dynamic" dynamicObject and here is the documentation of Json.Decode :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.decode(v=vs.111).aspx